# Android drawing chess pieces

Tags: java, android, bitmap, draw

I am currently working on developing an android version of chess, but I am having an issue with draw. I have set up a ChessboardView class that extends view and uses another helper class called Tile. The problem is that all of my pieces are being drawn in the correct places (my debugger shows when I click on tiles what piece I am hitting) but all of the images are showing up as Black Queens (I think because it's the last case that is hit in my switch statement, because when I get rid of it all of the pieces turn to black rooks). Here is relevant code:

ChessboardView.java:

```
protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas){
    final int width = getWidth();
    final int height = getHeight();
    this.squareSize = Math.min(
            getSquareSizeWidth(width),
            getSquareSizeHeight(height)
    );
    getOrigins(width,height);
    for(int col = 0; col < NUM_RC; col++){
        for(int row = 0; row < NUM_RC; row++){
            final int xCoord = getXCoord(col);
            final int yCoord = getYCoord(row);
            final Rect tileRect = new Rect(xCoord,yCoord,xCoord+squareSize,yCoord+squareSize);
            String loc = getRowString(row) + getColumnString(col);
            String piece = Chessboard.getPieceAtLocation(loc);
            tiles[col][row].setTileRect(tileRect);
            tiles[col][row].draw(canvas,piece,getContext());
        }
    }
}
```

Tile.java

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas,String piece, Context c){
    canvas.drawRect(tileRect, tileColor);
    if(!piece.equals("  ") && !piece.equals("##")){
        Bitmap pieceBM = null;
        switch(piece) {
            case "wp": {
                pieceBM = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.white_pawn);
            }
            case "wK": {
                pieceBM = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.white_king);
            }
            case "wB": {
                pieceBM = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.white_bishop);
            }
            case "wN": {
                pieceBM = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.white_knight);
            }
            case "wR": {
                pieceBM = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.white_rook);
            }
            case "wQ": {
                pieceBM = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.white_queen);
            }
            case "bp": {
                pieceBM = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.black_pawn);
            }
            case "bK": {
                pieceBM = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.black_king);
            }
            case "bB": {
                pieceBM = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.black_bishop);
            }
            case "bN": {
                pieceBM = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.black_knight);
            }
            case "bR": {
                pieceBM = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.black_rook);
            }
            case "bQ": {
                pieceBM = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), R.drawable.black_queen);
            }
        }
        canvas.drawBitmap(pieceBM,null,tileRect,null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put a `break;` at the end of each case.  Otherwise it falls down and executes the next case as well.

Comment: @atg963 and the braces (`{}`) are redundant; in a switch/case block the statements per case are delimited by the `case x:` and the `break`, except for the outer braces after `switch()` no braces are necessary for a switch/case block. Example and more information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html

Comment: And @GabeSechan: I know it's been quite a while since you wrote your answer, but I feel it might be nice for future visitors to include this in your answer.